# VBA Find Replace Based on Cell Values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I do not know what's wrong with my code below and am looking for a solution or any tips.

The goal is to name 8 separate ranges in 2 separate worksheets, and create a Find & Replace function.

- 4 of the ranges are part of an Excel chart that uses an index match formula and thus needs a Find & Replace function to update its values.
- The remaining 4 ranges are simply 4 cells I am using to reference what to Find in the formula and replace it with (topFind, topReplace, subFind and subReplace).

The worksheets are also named but I am receiving an error when it comes to referencing the first 4 Excel ranges (topAR, topExp, subAR and subExp) and can't get down to the Find & Replace function.

I welcome any help you can provide. Thank you in advance!

```
Sub FindReplace()

Dim topAR, topExp, subAR, subExp As Range
Dim topFind As Variant, topReplace As Variant
Dim subFind As Variant, subReplace As Variant
Dim wsTop As Worksheet, wsSub As Worksheet

wsTop = Workbook.Sheets("Top-20")
wsSub = Workbook.Sheets("Top US Sub-IG")

Set topAR = wsTop.Range.Cells("C8:E28")
Set topExp = wsTop.Range.Cells("M8:O28")
Set subAR = wsSub.Range.Cells("D7:F22")
Set subExp = wsSub.Range.Cells("L7:N22")

topFind = wsTop.cell.Location("H2")
topReplace = wsTop.cell.Location("I2")
subFind = wsSub.cell.Location("H2")
subReplace = wsSub.cell.Location("I2")

Range.topAR.Replace What:="topFind", Replacement:="topReplace", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False



Range.topAR.Replace What:="subFind", Replacement:="subReplace", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, 
ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Start by “setting” worksheet object : set wsTop = Workbook.Sheets("Top-20") / 
Set wsSub = Workbook.Sheets("Top US Sub-IG")

Comment: Explicitly “Dim” all variables otherwise not explicitly declared values will be taken as of Variant type: Dim topAR As Range, topExp As Range, subAR As Range, subExp As Range

Answer (score 0):

You have to adopt proper syntax for referencing Range objects

May be this is what you’re after

```
Sub FindReplace()

    Dim topAR As Range, topExp As Range, subAR As Range, subExp As Range
    Dim topFind As Variant, topReplace As Variant
    Dim subFind As Variant, subReplace As Variant
    Dim wsTop As Worksheet, wsSub As Worksheet

    Set wsTop = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Top-20")
    Set wsSub = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Top US Sub-IG")

    Set topAR = wsTop.Range("C8:E28")
    Set topExp = wsTop.Range("M8:O28")
    Set subAR = wsSub.Range("D7:F22")
    Set subExp = wsSub.Range("L7:N22")

    Set topFind = wsTop.Range("H2")
    Set topReplace = wsTop.Range("I2")
    Set subFind = wsSub.Range("H2")
    Set subReplace = wsSub.Range("I2")

    topAR.Replace What:=topFind.Value, Replacement:=topReplace.Value, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    subAR.Replace What:=subFind.Value, Replacement:=subReplace.Value, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried running the code step-by-step but received an error message at ' Set wsTop = Workbook.Sheets("Top-20")' stating 'Object required'. Do you think this is because I need to name the range first within Excel?

Comment: It now gives 'Subscript out of range'. Do you think this is because Excel is having trouble recognizing because I have 10+ worksheets within the workbook?

Comment: It is throwing the error in Set wsTop = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Top-20").

Comment: then it means that the Active Workbook has not any sheet named after "Top-20". If you are working with more than one workbook you'd better explicitly reference the name of the Workbook, like for instance `Set wsTop = WorkBooks("MyWorkbookName").Sheets("myWorkSheetName")`